# Detected when everything has finished downloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Using only HTML, CSS, and Javascript, has the web development world got to a stage where it is possible to display a loading message on the screen until absolutely everything has downloaded before the web page is displayed on the screen?

For example, display "loading", until all html, css, javascript, images etc etc have downloaded and can be displayed without the user seeing bits of the website still appearing after the load message has gone?

**UPDATE, .LOAD DOESN'T WORK:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>

        <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).load(function(){

                alert("loaded");

            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typically you would do this with JS. When the page is loading display something and when the page has loaded, hide it. To be honest, you should probably rethink your strategy if your page takes ages to download, otherwise noones going to be interested.

Comment: 'display "loading", until all html, css, javascript, images etc etc have downloaded and can be displayed without the user seeing bits of the website still appearing after the load message has gone' <- what would be the purpose of this?  Is there something wrong with the familiar queues the browser gives about the status of the document?

Comment: Please see the update in my question.  The `.load` is not generating the `alert` at all.  Apparently `.load` has been deprecated? http://api.jquery.com/category/events/document-loading/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely this will be achieved with jQuery and javascript no doubt:

```
$(function(){

    $('body').addClass('loader'); // this will show the loading gif

    $(window).load(function(){
        $('body').removeClass('loader'); // remove the loader when window gets loaded.
        $('#wrapper').show();    // show the wrapper div after everything loaded.
    });

});
```

Comment: see this url but make sure you clear the browser cache and cookies : http://jsfiddle.net/b8bTA/

Comment: Please see the update in my question.  The `.load` is not generating the `alert` at all.  Apparently `.load` has been deprecated? http://api.jquery.com/category/events/document-loading/

Comment: Ah, that was it.  I was using document.load instead of window.load.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [**$(window).load()**](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

```
$(window).load(function(){
    alert("");
})
```

Comment: Please see the update in my question.  The `.load` is not generating the `alert` at all.  Apparently `.load` has been deprecated? http://api.jquery.com/category/events/document-loading/

Comment: You can use $(window).load, I have updated my answer, document .load is not working could be the reason told by @oshirowanen

Answer (score -1):

Yes, `<body>` has a `onLoad` property described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_body_onload.asp), for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function done() {
    document.getElementById("loadingtext").innerHTML = "";
}
</script>

<body onload="done()">
<div id="loadingtext">Loading...</div>
```

But then, of course, it's easier to use a framework.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend w3schools as a reference, it's wrong as often as it's right and the quality is erratic. This is not how you should be adding events to the DOM. Use jQuery or the native `addEventListener`.

Comment: Really? Oh well sorry... I just mentioned onLoad because he specifically asked "Using only HTML, CSS, and Javascript", so I thought no jQuery involved.

Comment: `addEventListener` is the native function you should use. This is what jQuery uses, it just has a more accessible API :)

Comment: Right, but then again you'd have some browser compatibility issues.

Comment: Please see the update in my question.  The `.load` is not generating the `alert` at all.  Apparently `.load` has been deprecated? http://api.jquery.com/category/events/document-loading/